# Using an abstract base test class with approval tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, approval-tests

Assuming I had a very good reason to want to do the tests below, how could I setup approval tests to name the .approved files `UnitTest1.Test1.approved` instead of `BaseTest.Test1.approved`? Thanks

```
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Approvals.Verify(1);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Approvals.Verify(2);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : BaseTest
{
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        // some initialization
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2 : BaseTest
{
    public UnitTest2()
    {
        // some initialization
    }
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

Based on Llewellyn's suggestion I added the following code to the ctor of the base class:

```
public BaseTest()
{
    NamerFactory.AdditionalInformation = GetType().Name;
}
```

Works as expected, I get separate .approved files for each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting assumption. I am assuming you would want **both** UnitTest1.Test1.approved  & UnitTest2.Test1.approved

The short answer is not exactly, but there are a few work arounds.

### WorkAround #1 - NamerFactory (BaseTest.Test1.UnitTest1.approved.txt)

You could rewrite the test to be

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    NamerFactory.AdditionalInformation = this.GetType().Name;
    Approvals.Verify(2);
}
```

btw: this is better with the using statement if you are using the nightly builds from myget https://www.myget.org/gallery/approvaltests

```
using (NamerFactory.AsEnvironmentSpecificTest(() => this.GetType().Name))
{
    Approvals.Verify(1);
}
```

### WorkAround #2 - Call from OutsideClass (UnitTest1.Test1.approved.txt)

You can extract the bulk of the method and then Call it from  outside test. There is a good chance you might want all the functionality of a method, but still want the test to be in the extending class. The Approvals call does not need to be in the topmost test method. For example:

```
public abstract class BaseTest
{
    public void Verify1()
    {
        // other code to do stuff
        Approvals.Verify(1);
    }

}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1 : BaseTest
{
    public UnitTest1()
    {
        // some initialization
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Verify1();
    }
}
```